# CSS custom font: <b> works but font-weight:bold does not

Tags: custom-font, css

Hello I added a custom font in my css like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: dosis;
    src: url(Dosis-Regular.otf);
    font-weight:normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: dosis;
    src: url(Dosis-SemiBold.otf);
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

It works like this:

```
<b> This appears bold </b>
```

But not like this:

```
p{font-weight:bold;}  /* in CSS file */
<p> This does not appear bold </p> /* in HTML file */
```

Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it may be over-written somewhere else. try this:

```
p{font-weight:bold !important;}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. I don't know how I could miss that. I had multiple classes assigned to the paragraph and one overwrote it.